# Can the AccessToken Be Obtained by Using the authAccount.getAccessToken() Method After the Silent Login Is Successful

Tags: android, token, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, huawei-account

I am integrating Huawei account kit. I want to know whether the AccessToken can be obtained through authAccount by using the following code:

```
private void silentSignIn() {
        Task<AuthAccount> task = mAuthManager.silentSignIn();
        task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthAccount>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(AuthAccount authAccount) {

                Log.i(TAG, "silentSignIn success");
                Log.i(TAG, "touxiang: "+authAccount.getAvatarUriString());
            }
        });
        task.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Exception e) {
                //if Failed use getSignInIntent
                if (e instanceof ApiException) {
                    ApiException apiException = (ApiException) e;
                    signIn();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Could anyone give any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain a user-level AccessToken through silent sign-in.

1. First you need to check how the `mAuthManager` object is initialized:

   [image]
2. The `mAuthManager` object can be initialized only when the following conditions are met:

```
//Call the default constructor of HuaweiIdAuthParamsHelper to set authorization parameters.
AccountAuthParams silentSignInParams = new AccountAuthParamsHelper(AccountAuthParams.DEFAULT_AUTH_REQUEST_PARAM)
        .setAccessToken()
        .createParams();
//Call the getService method of HuaweiIdAuthManager to initialize the HuaweiIdAuthService object.
AccountAuthService mAuthManager = AccountAuthManager.getService(getApplicationContext(), silentSignInParams);
//Call the HuaweiIdAuthService.silentSignIn method to send a silent sign-in request.
Task<AuthAccount> task = mAuthManager.silentSignIn();
```

The `AccountAuthParams` object is required when the `mAuthManager` object is initialized. When creating this object, you must set the `.setAccessToken()` method to obtain the user-level access token using the `authHuaweiId.getAccessToken()` method.

3. You could check whether you have set the `.setAccessToken()` method.